# Publishing website on IIS error

Tags: asp.net

Hi everyone when i publish my website via IIS, I get this error code as you can see at below. Can you help me ?

```
 Configuration Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

    Source Error: 


    Line 27:       </assemblies>
    Line 28:     </compilation>
    Line 29:     <authentication mode="Forms">
    Line 30:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    Line 31:     </authentication>


    Source File: C:\Users\furkan\Desktop\WebCity\webcity\web.config    Line: 29
```

Then I converted my root dictionary to Application but I get this error

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error: 


Line 17:   <system.web>
Line 18:     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
Line 19:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 20:       <assemblies>
Line 21:         <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />


Source File: C:\Users\furkan\Desktop\WebCity\WebCity\web.config    Line: 19
```

Comment: This is now a different issue. The first problem was that your site wasn't an application. Now, you either don't have Asp.Net 4.0 installed, or your application is configured in IIS to use Asp.Net 2.0. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first issue was this:

This usually means you have not configured the directory for your website as an application. Open up IIS Manager, find the root directory for your website (where web.config is), right click, and select "Convert to Application".

For the new issue, it's a problem of the .NET version. You either don't have asp.net 4.0 installed, or you have the application pool set to use the wrong framework. It's probably the latter, so go to the advanced setting for your site, select the Application Pool setting, and choose an Application Pool called ASP.NET 4.0, or any other that uses the 4.0 framework. If there aren't any, then you need to install .NET 4.0

[image: Choosing an app pool:]

Comment: I converted root directory but i get error  i will edit my question you will see

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have multiple web.configs in a sub directory somewhere?
Link describing the problem [here](http://forums.devarticles.com/net-development-43/section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level-10027.html)