# Getting Configuration Error?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have downloaded a online shopping project made in asp.net from

[http://prakashjha.codeplex.com/]

and trying to execute it in visual studio 2012 but i am getting this error

```
 Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:


Line 39:         <!--<roleManager enabled="true" />-->
Line 40:         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 41:       <authentication mode="Forms" >
Line 42:           
Line 43:         <forms  defaultUrl="default.aspx" loginUrl="login1.aspx"   cookieless="AutoDetect"  ></forms>
```

i have configured iis server by going to 
Control Panel then
Programs then
Turn Windows on or off
Then selecting iis
but still it is giving the same error.
Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you create its virtual directory?

Comment: this link 'http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138' will help you to create a virtual directory. after create a virtual directory, first test the application, if got error then update this post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing website on IIS error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069058/publishing-website-on-iis-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you have added this application to the sites in IIS then please for the development period change `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />` to `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />` because IIS doesnot support debugging and in the Advanced Settings of the site in IIS be sure to change Application Pool to ASP.NETv4.0 and you will be done.